# How to delete intermediate object files in makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I want to know how to force make to delete .o files after building the library in a correct way.

```
all: libtest.a

libtest.a: foo.o bar.o
    ar r $@ $?

%.o : %.c
    gcc -o $@ -c $<
```

The problem with marking the .o files as `.INTERMEDIATE` is that all the .o files are being recompiled if even one source file changes, even though they are already present in the archive. Is there a way to achieve this. Have the object files deleted and not recompile unchanged source files to update the library.

Comment: afaik, if you delete all .o's after compiling the library, you're gonna have to create them again to compile the library again, even if only one of the source files changes

Comment: But the unchanged object files are never needed while updating a library. Suppose the .o files are not deleted and only foo.c changes. Then the library can be updated with simple "ar r libtest.a foo.o". bar.o wont even be needed. But if bar.o is missing it will recompile it anyways.

Comment: they are needed, but since they didn't change at all, you don't have to create them again, just the ones that changed. It goes like this: check which ones changed, recreate .o for that one, take all .o's and create library

Comment: How are they needed? The command "ar r libtest.a foo.o", which is what make would normally invoke, doesn't contain bar.o at all. The file is already present in the archive. Only updated files are needed to be present.

Comment: The problem arises here because of way make generates the dependencies. My question is if there is a way to do it correctly such that I dont need to keep the .o files around.

Comment: How do you expect make to know that it doesn't need them? You haven't told it anything like that. Perhaps try using the special support make has for [using make to Update Archive Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Archives)? (I don't know that it will work but given that it is special support it might.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `foo.c` has been changed, then `libtest.a` is out of date, so Make must rebuild `foo.o` and then `libtest.a`. But `bar.o` is a prerequisite of `libtest.a` too, so Make cannot execute the `libtest.a` rule until `bar.o` is present, so it rebuilds `bar.o` as well.

The best solution (I know of) is to treat the library as a set of independent targets:

```
.PHONY: all
all: libtest.a(foo.o bar.o)

libtest.a(%.o): %.o
    ar r libtest.a $^
```

(Make can handle archive members this way, but even if it couldn't, we could still use this approach with some phony targets.)

Comment: Is this method safe for parallel builds?

Comment: @user1353535: I suppose that depends on whether `ar` is thread-safe; therefore I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Would changing the `ar` line to `ar r $@ $? && rm *.o` (or something similar work?

Comment: That wont help since all the .o files will have to be rebuilt the next time even a single source file changes.